# Jquery how to update overlay's position on overlaid element position's change

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, overlay

I have the following elements: One text box over another for a watermark effect and validation. There is no problem with the position as I set the overlay's coordinates on body.ready but the problem comes when one of the neighbouring containers is resized the overlaid element's position get changed and my overlaying element gets wrong position. Is there a way(event) to see when the overlaid container is changing top and left coordinates and then change the top and left coordinates of the overlaying one. Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you keep them both within a wrapper element, with `position: relative`?

Comment: It may work but when I set my overlay to position relative I can't seem to make them overlap properly because the page thinks that there is an element there and leaves a gap where the element is supposed to be. And when the element's display is set to none the gap dissapears

Comment: Oh I gave the container relative and it worked thank you :)

Comment: You misunderstood me. You should have setup like this: `<div><textarea><textarea><textarea><textarea></div>`. The div should have `position: relative`, while the textarea's should both have `position: absolute; top:0; left: 0;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(simply posting the answer from the comment above)

You should give your wrapper `position: relative`:

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <textarea><textarea>
    <textarea><textarea>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
    position: relative;
}
textarea {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
}
```